# Unable to use factory() in Test's setUp() method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've encountered an error when refactoring my Laravel tests by adding at `setUp()` method.

This works as expected:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\Person;
use Tests\TestCase;

class MembershipTicketsTest extends TestCase
{

public function test_a_non_member_cannot_list_redeemable_events()
{
    $user = Person::factory()->create();

    $this->actingAs($user);

    $this->get(route('event.index'))->assertStatus(302)->assertRedirect(route('membership.create'));
}
```

Where as this returns the error `Unknown formatter "firstName"`:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\Person;
use Tests\TestCase;

class MembershipTicketsTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $user;

    protected function setUp() : void
    {
        $this->user = Person::factory()->create();
    }

    public function test_a_non_member_cannot_list_redeemable_events()
    {

        $this->actingAs($this->user);

        $this->get(route('event.index'))->assertStatus(302)->assertRedirect(route('membership.create'));
    }
```

Every solution to this error I've found says to make sure that you have `use Tests\TestCase;` in your file, which I do.

I presume this means I cannot use factories in the `setUp()` method of a test in Laravel. Is this true, and why is it the case?

Comment: Do you have `CreatesApplication` trait in your *TestCase*? You also need to migrate your db in order to create any model instances.

Comment: try changing setUp() to `public` things are run from different levels in the test class hierarchy